# Can shared variable between threads be at any point incomplete/invalid?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's consider this piece of code:

```java
class Foo {
  //Possibly any other immutable type
  static Instant ins = Instant.now();

  static void thread1() {
    while(true) System.out.println(ins.toString());
  }

  static void thread2() {
    while(true) ins=Instant.now();
  }
}
```

(Assuming `thread1` and `thread2` are run in different threads)

Can this result in any undefined behaviour or crash directly?

Can, at any point, have `thread1` reference to invalid object? (invalid meaning incomplete or null, not "old")

Will any value from `thread2` be "flushed" from the cache at some point?

Comment: [What operations in Java are considered atomic?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4756578)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References cannot be undefined or invalid.  They can be `null`.  On a 32 bit system, 64 bit primitives (`long` and `double`) can experience "word tearing" where the upper 32 bits and the lower 32 bits do not agree.

Language spec on non-atomic treatment of `long` and `double`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7  That same section explains that "references are always atomic."

It's not guaranteed that values will be "flushed from a cache."  In the case of your code above, with such a small loop, it's possible that values will be hoisted into registers for speed, and won't be cache at all.  There's no way to flush a register.